# Anchor: Error when trying to initialize a program derived account (PDA)

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I get the below error whenever try to initialize PDA account:

`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`

```rust
#[program]
pub mod myprogram {
    use super::*;

 pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, bump:u8) -> ProgramResult {
        let base_account: &mut Account<BaseAccount> = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        base_account.bump = bump;
        base_account.counter = Some(0);
        return Ok(());
    }
}



#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump:u8)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"seed".as_ref()], 
        bump, init, payer = creator, space = 20000)]
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(address = system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct BaseAccount {
    pub counter: Option<u64>,
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

My test code looks like this:

```js
const [baseAccountPDA, baseAccountPDABump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [Buffer.from("seed")],
      program.programId
    );

    await program.rpc.initialize(baseAccountPDABump, {
      accounts: {
        baseAccount: baseAccountPDA,
        creator: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [],
    });
```

I have tried using a newly generated keypair as the creator, and adding that keypair to the signers, but i cannot seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you mentioned you should close test-validator terminal before execute

```
anchor test
```

anchor run test-validator for you by itself and after test you can see the test-ledger folder inside your solana anchor project root
another point is you should add test-ledger folder to your .gitignore file.
maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this code is the correct way to create a PDA :) I had a test-validator running so it was trying to execute against a previously existing contract!